# Purpose of Using namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, iostream, using

What does `using namespace std;` contain?
As all IO related functions exists in IOstream header file, why we should use both IOStream and Std namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces allow to group entities like classes, objects and functions under a name. 
This way the global scope can be divided in "sub-scopes", each one with its own name.

The format of namespaces is:

```
 namespace identifier
 {
     entities
 }
```

For eg

```
// using
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}

int main () {
  using namespace first;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
  cout << second::x << endl;
  cout << second::y << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

you can read more about it in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers here, it's important to note the difference between a **using declaration** and a **using directive**.

```
using namespace std;
```

Is a **using directive** and allows *all* names within that namespace to be used without qualification. Eg:

```
using namespace std;
string myStdString;
cout << myStdString << endl;
```

This contrasts with:

```
using std::string;
```

Is a **using declaration** and allows a particular name from the specified namespace to be used without qualification. The following will not compile:

```
using std::string;
string myStdString; // Fine.
cout << myStdString << endl; // cout and endl need qualification - std::
```

the `using` keywords are bound by scope:

```
void Foo()
{
    {
        using namespace std;
        string myStdString; // Fine.
    }
    string outOfScope; // Using directive out of scope.
    std::string qualified; // OK
}
```

It's typically a bad idea to put a using directive in the global scope of a header file - unless you are quite sure anything that includes that file will not contain conflicting class names, and produce nasty side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces allows us to group a set of global classes, objects and/or functions under a name. If you specify `using namespace std` then you don't have to put `std::` throughout your code. The program will know to look in the std library to find the object. Namespace std contains all the classes, objects and functions of the standard C++ library.